# How to get data form API using TypeScript and Each All Data to html

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
const container: HTMLElement | any = document.getElementById("appPokemon");
const allApps: number = 100;

interface appList {
  auto_id: number;
  application_name: string;
  
}

const fetchData = (): void => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= allApps; i++) {
    getAllApp(i);
  }
};

const getAllApp = async (id: number): Promise<void> => {
  const data: Response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/userApps/list`);
  const allDatas: any = await data.json();
  const pokemonType: string = allDatas.types
    .map((poke: any) => poke.type.name)
    .join(", ");

  const transformedPokemon = {
    auto_id: allDatas.auto_id,
    application_name: allDatas.application_name,
    
  };

  showPokemon(transformedPokemon);
};

const showPokemon = (appsData: appList): void => {
  let output: string = `
        <div class="card">
            <span class="card--id">#${appsData.auto_id}</span>
           
            <h1 class="card--name">${appsData.application_name}</h1>
           
        </div>
    `;
  container.innerHTML += output;
};

fetchData();
```

This is my Data API I want to show this Data to html by TypeScript

```
{
"auto_id": 3,
"application_id": "APP001",
"application_name": "Billing",
"application_image": "icon.png",
"application_icon": null,
"application_base_url": "http://catsinfo.cats.com.kh/",
"application_url": "becatsv2/"
},
{
"auto_id": 17,
"application_id": "APP010",
"application_name": "Booking Car",
"application_image": "icon.png",
"application_icon": "flaticon-truck",
"application_base_url": "http://catsinfo.cats.com.kh/",
"application_url": "bookingcar"
},
{
"auto_id": 18,
"application_id": "APP011",
"application_name": "Fixed Asset",
"application_image": "icon.png",
"application_icon": "flaticon2-gear",
"application_base_url": "http://10.100.0.9:8883",
"application_url": "/"
},
```

This is all my error And I want to use TypeScript to Read all data form API and show on html and I meet this error want I compiler TypeScript to JavaScript don't Show anything like error oh Data
Sorry for My English and thank before you help me

Comment: Hello. A little confused. The JSON you post does not seem related to your code? Also, are you getting any errors? If so, what are they?

Comment: Example: I have this JSON and I want to show this JSON with HTML by using TypeScript How Can I do this

Comment: In your code though you try to reference `allDatas.types` and `poke.type.name`, but `types` and `type.name` do not appear in the JSON.

Comment: The way your code is currently written, it makes the API look like it should have the data in the format: `{ types: [{ type: { name: "someName" } }] }`

Comment: Note and thank i must be try to fix this code

Comment: and that you have any debug this problem like to change style code to get JSON data to show on html